# Convert a numpy bool array to int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-manipulation

I have a numpy array (dtype bool) representing an array of bits. For example, the array `np.array([True, False, False], dtype=bool)` represents the number 4 (indeed, `bin(4) == 0b100`).

I would like to convert the numpy array to an integer (`4` in the previous example).

So far I've tried with an iterative approach:

```
bits = np.array([True, False, False], dtype=bool)
n = 0
for bit in bits:
    n = (n << 1) | bit
```

This approach does work, but I would prefer something that does not iterate over every element of the array, possibly a numpy built-in method.

I also tried using [`numpy.packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html) (together with [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), because `packbits` always automatically pad to the right, and not to the left):

```
bits = np.array([True, False, False], dtype=bool)
n = np.packbits(np.pad(bits, ((8 - len(bits) % 8) % 8, 0))).item()
```

This approach only works for arrays with 8 or less elements. Indeed, if you try to use a longer array you end up having multiple results (because apparently `packbits` not only pads to the right but also converts every single byte to a number):

```
bits = np.array(
    [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    dtype=bool,
)
n = np.packbits(np.pad(bits, ((8 - len(bits) % 8) % 8, 0)))
print(n) # this prints [1 0], but I need it to return 256
```

Expected behavior:

```
np.array([True, True], dtype=bool) --> 3
np.array([True, True, False], dtype=bool) --> 6
np.array([True, False, False, True, True], dtype=bool) --> 19
np.array([True, False, False, False, False,
          False, False, True, False, False], dtype=bool) --> 516
```

Comment: I think the last is 516 (512+4) and not 518.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by generating the power of two starting from the biggest one (eg. `[16, 8, 4, 2, 1]`), and then multiply this by `bits` before doing the final sum:

```py
powers = 1 << np.arange(bits.size, dtype=np.uint64)[::-1]
result = np.sum(powers * bits)
```

This is equivalent of doing: `2**n * bits[0] + 2**(n-1) * bits[1] + ... + 2**0 * bits[n]`.
Note that the final value needs to fit in 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [numpy.logspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html):

```
import numpy as np
bits = np.array([True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],dtype=bool,)
bits=bits[::-1]
result = np.sum(np.logspace(0, bits.size-1, num=bits.size, base=2) * bits, dtype=np.int)
```

This outputs:

```
print(result)
256
```